# How to fetch phone number in jsoup document using regex

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am using jsoup to connect to url and load document after that i use regex to check document contain it or not.But it fails in some cases. following code fetch all phone number from some urls but fails in others such as http://www.wellclean.com/ while i checked that document contain phone number while printing doc.

```
String regex_num = "^\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex_num);
Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
        .maxBodySize(0)
        .timeout(600000)
        .get();

Elements Phone_Num=doc.getElementsMatchingOwnText(pattern);// match regex in doc
if(!Phone_Num.isEmpty()) // if phone number exist
{
    System.out.println("Phone number found!");
    for(Element e : Phone_Num)
    {
        PNUM=PNUM+e.text().toString()+" & "; // store all phone number seperated by &
    }

}
```

when i print doc it contains phone number in following format

```
<div class="contact_address">
     <div class="contact_column_1">
      2261 N. Clybourn Ave.
    <br> Chicago, IL 60614
    <br> Ph: (773) 348.2226
    <br> 
    <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=2261+N.+Clybourn+Ave.Chicago,+IL+60614&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=41.923214,-87.666462&amp;sspn=0.014417,0.029268&amp;gl=us&amp;hnear=2261+N+Clybourn+Ave,+Chicago,+Cook,+Illinois+60614&amp;t=m&amp;z=17" target="_new"><img src="/wp-content/themes/artgallery_3.0/images/map.png" alt="map"></a>
    <br> Hours:
    <br> M-S 7:30am – 7:00pm
    <br> Sun 9:00am – 5:00pm
   </div> 
   <div class="contact_column_2">
    &nbsp;
    <br>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't match given HTML, because your pattern `^\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}$` expresses condition, that element you are looking for **has** to contain body that matches given pattern completely. It is because you used `^` in the beginning and `$` in the end of the pattern, which is OK in most cases - you want to limit all matchings restrictively.

This pattern works fine in combination with

```
Document.getElementsMatchingOwnText(Pattern pattern)
```

method if phone number you are looking for is the only body of HTML tag, e.g. it would work if HTML you are parsing would look like this:

```
<br> Ph: <span>(773) 348.2226</span>
```

### How to solve it?

In this case you will have to update your pattern to allow matching elements where phone number is just a part of a body:

```
\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}
```

When you run your program now you will see that calling `e.text()` returns

```
2261 N. Clybourn Ave. Chicago, IL 60614 Ph: (773) 348.2226 Hours: M-S 7:30am – 7:00pm Sun 9:00am – 5:00pm
```

because this is a full body in plain text for of a `<div class="contact_column_1">` element. In this case you will have to extract phone number using same pattern, e.g.

```
for(Element e : Phone_Num)
{
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(e.text());
    if (matcher.find()) {
        PNUM += matcher.group(0).trim() + " & "; // store all phone number seperated by &
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to work on your regex expression.

You are using method getElementsMatchingOwnText and you have ^ and $ in your regex, that means you are able to find only phone numbers that span whole tag i.e. `<tag>(773) 348.2226</tag>.`

In your example html phone number is only a part of tag that stars with `<div class="contact_column_1">`